# Handle DTOs with interior objects when posting a file with request DTO to a server in servicestack

Tags: c#, file-upload, servicestack

I am trying to pass both a file and a request DTO to servicestack using `JsonServiceClient` and it's `PostFileWithRequest<ResponseType>(fileStream, fileName, RequestType)` function.

The issue arises when the request is handled by the service handler like so:

```
public object Any(StoreRequest request)
{
    return ToResponse(Store(request).Result);
}
```

The request object contains a `Document` object specified as such:

```
public class File : MegaObject
{
    public CustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    // more functions here
}
```

Where `MegaObject` is a custom object providing the `Id` and `LastUpdated` fields to all objects in use by the project.

When making a request using `JsonServiceClient.Post(ResponseType)` I receive the Attachment object as expected, however when using `PostFileWithRequest` the `CustomObject` data field is set to null before any of the code in the above function is run. I ran into a similar issue earlier in development due to trying to generalize more of the system, however this does not appear to be the case.

This code is currently being run out of a UnitTest file and is specified as such:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:2000/");

var request = new StoreRequest()
{
    Document = new File()
    {
        Id = null,
        Name = "foo",
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        LastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
        CustomObject = new CustomObject()
        {
            Id = /* Predefined string value */,
            string1 = "foo",
            string2 = "bar"
        },
        MimeType = /* Relevant Mimetype to the file being loaded at the same time */,
    } 
};

// put test file into the db
//POST /files

StoreResponse response;    

// this works fine
response = client.Post(request); 

// this one loses data about the custom object.     
response =  client.PostFileWithRequest<StoreResponse>(
                                  File.Open("C:\\" + path, FileMode.Open), 
                                  path, request, "upload"); 

// assert file was actually stored and was stored correctly...
```

The CustomObject is defined as:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomObject : MegaObjectRef
{
    [DataMember(Name = "String1")]
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "String2")]
    public string String2 { get; set; }

    public CustomObject() {}
}
```

To be clear I am receiving the request object with the file as expected, however the `CustomObject` property in the request document is set to null when it should not be and is causing null reference errors.

Am I doing something wrong here? or should I be trying to send my `File` document and the file itself in separate POSTs to ServiceStack?

Comment: Please update question to include the class definition of `CustomObject` as well as the raw HTTP Request Headers + Body (can strip out the file contents)

Comment: @mythz i've added the definition of `CustomObject` but am not sure how to retrieve/find the http request headers & body

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Also if you're going to use `[DataContract]` annotations you should be using them for the entire DTO, e.g. `MegaObjectRef` and `StoreRequest` - but I don't see why you've decided to use them for `CustomObject` since the DataMember aliases have the same name as the property.

Comment: Oh ok, it was something that most of the examples which I had been looking at included, just trying to get my head around fiddler now and get you those headers and such

Comment: @mythz I am having difficulty retrieving those header and body raw data for you as i cannot seem to find the requests with fiddler when the project executes. Further testing has shown that the `File` object being passed has all of it's variables aside from primitive types set to their default values, ie null for objects and {DATE 12:00:00 AM} for the `DateTime` objects. This is very reminiscent of the issues regarding serialization that were occurring due to usage of generic types.

Comment: primitive default values are their natural state, I.e. it's what they would be if they were left untouched so it's not related to an existing issue. What we need to find out is why, which is what the raw HTTP Headers would help identify which is the purpose of Fiddler. If you can't get the HTTP Headers can you put together a small stand-alone project that I can run locally to see the issue (I.e on Github), I'll be able to get the Headers myself.

Comment: Or since you say the issue only happens with nested objects, as a workaround you can flatten your DTO (I.e pull out properties into the main DTO) so it doesn't use any nested objects.

Comment: We managed to identify the issue and it had been noted before here: http://www.hprm.info/blog/2016/11/29/sending-service-actions-with-postfilewithrequest applying the same fix solved the issue with our project. Additionally the documentation states that the parser can handle local time `DateTime` objects, however until we switched to UTC time it was not serializing and serializing properly.